# RxJava what's difference Observable.just vs Observable.fromCallable?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a question about the difference between Observable.just and Observable.fromCallable.

I have a "service" class like this:

```
class Service {
    var cachedToken: String = ""
        get() {
            if (needToRefreshToken()) {
                refresh()    // Can throw Exception!!!
            }

            return token
        }
}
```

And below code is calling upper code like:

```
Observable.just(service.cachedToken)
    .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
    .observeOn(uiScheduler)
    .subscribe({ isSuccess ->
        view.showSomething()
    }, {
        view.showError()    // this code is never called!!!
    })
```

I expected that "view.showError()" method be called when some exception occurs during the "refresh()" token.

But it doesn't.

So I changed the Observable.just => Observable.fromCallable like below:

```
Observable.fromCallable{ service.cachedToken }
    .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
    .observeOn(uiScheduler)
    .subscribe({ isSuccess ->
        view.showSomething()
    }, {
        view.showError()
    })
```

And then it works fine.

In normal case, both codes (just and fromCallable) works fine.
"view.showSomething()" is called correctly.
But the only exceptional case, they work differently

What difference???

Comment: What's the difference between a constant and a calculation?

Comment: @akarnokd, normal case both work fine. But the only exceptional case, the result is not the same.

Comment: "Observable.just()" create Observable once. while fromCallable create new observable every time after  onComplete or onError.

Answer (score 1):

From the documents

**Observable.just**

> Returns an Observable that ,signals the given (constant reference) item
>   and then completes.

**Observable.fromCallable**

> Returns an Observable that, when an observer subscribes to it, invokes
>   a function you specify and then emits the value returned from that
>   function.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `just` isn't special to RxJava. Arguments are always evaluated before method is called, so

```
Observable.just(service.cachedToken)...
```

is the same as

```
val x = service.cachedToken
Observable.just(x)...
```

So it only calls `cachedToken`'s `get` once. If `get` throws an exception, `Observable.just` call is never reached in the first place, so you still won't get `view.showError()`.

Answer (score 0):

If we compare code of `SingleJust` and `SingleFromCallable`, we can see what is happening here.

`SinbleJust`

```
@Override
protected void subscribeActual(SingleObserver<? super T> observer) {
    observer.onSubscribe(Disposables.disposed());
    observer.onSuccess(value);
}
```

`SingleFromCallable`

```
@Override
protected void subscribeActual(SingleObserver<? super T> observer) {
    Disposable d = Disposables.empty();
    observer.onSubscribe(d);

    if (d.isDisposed()) {
        return;
    }
    T value;

    try {
        value = ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(callable.call(), "The callable returned a null value");
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Exceptions.throwIfFatal(ex);
        if (!d.isDisposed()) {
            observer.onError(ex);
        } else {
            RxJavaPlugins.onError(ex);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (!d.isDisposed()) {
        observer.onSuccess(value);
    }
}
```